# Get 404 render view ejs with express js

Tags: javascript, express, http-status-code-404, ejs

I use express ejs on my backend and frontend. I have made a route to display the dashboard on the admin page. but I get 404 error to render view when I enter my url http: // localhost: 3000 /admin, here are some of my code:

**app.js**

```
var createError  = require('http-errors');
var express      = require('express');
var path         = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger       = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(indexRouter);
app.use('/admin', admin);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//  res.status(404).render('error/404')
// });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error/404');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**controller dashboard.js**

```
exports.getDashboard = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('dashboard', {
        pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
        path: 'admin/page/dashboard'
    });
};
```

**my admin route admin.js**

```
const path = require('path');

var express = require('express');

const adminController = require('../controllers/backend/dashboard');

var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/admin', adminController.getDashboard);

module.exports = router;
```

thank you, please help me for this issue

Answer (score 1):

in app.js you already have route `/admin` then again in admin.js, so it will be accessible with `localhost:3000/admin/admin`.

Change your admin.js to

```
const path = require('path');

var express = require('express');

const adminController = require('../controllers/backend/dashboard');

var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', adminController.getDashboard);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
const adminController = require('../controllers/backend/dashboard');
```

You are not exporting a default option from controller dashboard so you need to add curly braces like this:

```
const { adminController } = require('../controllers/backend/dashboard');
```

Try this and let me know! :)

Comment: @AZ_ is also correct, implement his part of solution as well!